# I'm trying to create a discord bot. As a project to test and expand my python knowledge. But I can't start the Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
#main.py

import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

```
#responses.py

import random 

def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == "Hello":
        return "Hi"
    
    if p_message == "Roll":
        return str(random.randint(1,2))

    if p_message == "!help":
        return "This is a help message."
```

```
#bot.py

import discord
import responses

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try: 
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response)if is_private else await message.chanel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = '################################################################'
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now runing!')


    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user: 
            return
        
        username = str(message.author())
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        if user_message[0] == "?":
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private = True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private = False)

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

I ran the code in VS code and got an error message saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\#####\Desktop\Python Scripts\Discor_Bot\main.py", line 4, in <module>     
    bot.run_discord_bot()
  File "c:\Users\#####\Desktop\Python Scripts\Discor_Bot\bot.py", line 13, in run_discord_bot
    client = discord.Client()
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
PS C:\Users\#####\Desktop\Python Scripts\Discor_Bot>
```

I have no idea how to interpret the error so i tried rearanging the nesting but to no avail. Some help hol'd be mutch apriciated.

To note; I folowed this tutorial when building this simple bot.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoDLj0IzZMU&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

Your bot is missing its intents. For example default intents:

```
def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = '##########################'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

check [discordpy documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents) for further information about intents.

Answer (score 0):

the error message says: the intents argument ist missing ...

you should define the intents where you set the client

change the
`client = discord.Client()`
to

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True # use this so that the bot can also read messages, else the on_message function wont work
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```